# How To Authenticate In Symfony2 Using Two Different Tables

Tags: symfony, authentication

I have two tables in this project of mine. One table is for the site admin which stores all the admin users details, and the other table stores all the login data for clients to the site.

At the moment, I can log in using the admin details fine. However, I am now trying to login with the client details and it doesn't seem to be working. So far, when a user clicks on a link it will go to /clientarea/login. This page loads up fine. But when I try to log in I get an error.

The error I am getting is this:

> Unable to find the controller for path "/clientarea/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?

In my security.yml file, I have the following code: (By the way, I'm using plaintext for development only, it will be changed when it goes live):

```
providers:
    admin_db:
        entity: { class: Shout\AdminBundle\Entity\User, property: username }
    client_db:
        entity: { class: Shout\AdminBundle\Entity\Userclients, property: username }

encoders:
    Shout\AdminBundle\Entity\User: 
        algorithm: plaintext 
    Shout\AdminBundle\Entity\Userclients: 
        algorithm: plaintext 

firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        provider: admin_db
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /index
    client_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        provider: client_db
        form_login:
            check_path: /clientarea/login_check
            login_path: /clientarea/login
        logout:
            path:   /clientarea/logout
            target: /index

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/clientarea/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/clientarea, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

In my routing.yml I have this code:

```
login:
    pattern:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: ShoutAdminBundle:Security:login }

    login_check:
        pattern:   /login_check

    logout:
        pattern:   /logout

    clientlogin:
        pattern:   /clientarea/login
        defaults:  { _controller: ShoutAdminBundle:Security:clientlogin }

    clientlogin_check:
        pattern:   /clientarea/login_check

    clientlogout:
        pattern:   /clientarea/logout
```

Here is the code in the controller. The code is identical for the login and clientlogin functions, the only thing that is different is the twig file they point to:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$session = $request->getSession();

// get the login error if there is one
if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
    $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
} else {
    $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
}

return $this->render('ShoutAdminBundle:Security:clientlogin.html.twig', array(
    // last username entered by the user
    'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
    'error'         => $error,
));
```

The action path of the Client Login form points to clientlogin_check.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get it working, but in a very basic way. I don't have time due to a deadline to make the login pages pretty looking.

But here is the code:

```
    client_area:
        pattern: ^/clientarea
        anonymous: ~
        provider: client_db
        http_basic:
            realm: "Secured Client Area"
```

Basically, you can have users from more than one table. However, I have still been unable to make it work using a proper login form. But the basic HTTP login box works just as well for what I'm doing.